# Python - AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'print_out'

Tags: python-2.7

I'm learning python for a college course, which I've never used before. I've been having problems launching this code. Can I get some help??

```
    import webapp2


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p = Page()
        self.response.write(p.print_out())


class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.css = "css/style.css"
        self.title = "Simple Form"
        self.head = """
           <!DOCTYPE HTML>
         <html>
         <head>
         <title>{self.title}</title>
         <link href="{self.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
         </head>
         """
        self.body = """
         <body>
         <div id="form">
         <form method="GET">
         <h1>Contact Us</h1>
         <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="80" value="Name"/>
         <br/>
         <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="80" value="Phone Number"></input>
         <br/>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="80" value="E-Mail"></input>
         <br/>
         <label for="contact">Contact Time:</label>
         <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="Morning">Morning</input>
         <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="Mid-Day">Mid-Day</input>
         <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact" value="Afternoon">Afternoon</input>
         <br/>
         <label for="type">Prefered Contact Method:</label>
         <select name="type">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
         <option value="email">E-Mail</option>
         <option value="txtmsg">Text Message</option>
         </select>
         <br/>
         <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Male">Male</input>
         <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Female">Female</input>
         <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Neutral">Neutral</input>
         <br/>
         <label for="message">Message:</label>
         <br/>
         <textarea></textarea>
         <br/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </form>
         </div>
         </body>
         """
        self.close = """
         </html>
         """

        def print_out(self):
            all = self.head + self.body + self.close
            all = all.format(**locals())
            return all


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication({
    ('/', MainHandler)
}, debug=True)
```

I'm working off of Chrome, if it matters. I've tried launching in other browsers. I read the error it's giving me and this is what it was:

File "/Users/judia_krakowski/Desktop/Python/simple-form/main.py", line 23, in get
    self.response.write(p.print_out())
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'print_out'

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can find in the code is the indentations of the constructor and the `print_out` function. Your `print_out` functions seems to be declared within the constructor. I think it will work when you indent it at the same level as the constructor.

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print_out(self):
        pass
```

instead of:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Some code
    def print_out(self):
         pass
```

`